# ADFS, WindowsIdentity & EFCore

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-core, adfs, ef-core-2.1

I have the following issue. I need to access the database and execute queries with AD Domain user. So the connection string must be Integrated Security = True. The project architecture is service oriented, meaning many interconnected services are accessing the database, and should do that in context of the logged in AD user.

The user is logs in via ADFS. After the user successfully logs in, the JWT token is passed around the services. In the JWT token there is the UPN claim.

I've tried using the S4UClient libraries, or the WindowsIdentity(string upn) ctor, and so far that seems like a nice option to impersonate based on the UPN claim, even though there are limitations like impersonation and async code...

My question is: Is there another way to make architecture like this work, using **.NET CORE 2+** other than impersonating in code using WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated() and using S4UClient libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: Would really like to know too. I find it astonishingly hard to find a blog post / sample code that explains how to do something I would expect to be fairly common.